# how can i parse a json that contains Geo-coordinates?

Tags: android, json

i have this object in a Json file and i succeded at parsing many objects but i couldn't parse this one :

`"advertiser_marker_geocoord": "33.848463,-7.033653"`

how can i parse it using java?

Answer (score 1):

// Here json is assumed to be a json object accompanied from response you would be getting.

```
String value = json.getString("advertiser_marker_geocoord");
```

now split values on behalf of , String arr[] = value.split(",");

If you want me share exact code.. please share the exact json that you are getting

Comment: ok "FeaturedDeal": (deal de jours)
{"childs": [],"advertiser_name": "Playland", 
 "deal_id": 2488, 
 "tipping_point": 0,"image3": "http://mydeal.ma/site_media/deal_images/mobile/img3_1328.jpg", 
 "advertiser_email": "malikbensouda@hotmail.com", 
 "deal_price": "95.00","end_date": "2012-03-08 00:00:00", 
 "advertiser_marker_geocoord": "33.848463,-7.033653", 
 "advertiser_cell": "0661977474",
 "city_name": "Casablanca", 
 "image2": "http://mydeal.ma/site_media/deal_images/mobile/img2_1372.jpg",
 "image1": "http://mydeal.ma/site_media/deal_images/mobile/img1_1536.jpg" 
  }

Comment: Hope you got exact idea from my code.. Also the shared json has error the ";" at some places around "." are invalid.. So json that you have shared with me is not correct

Comment: it's incorrect because i can show you the whole Json file that i have to parse so i was obliged to cut a lot of data and try to reduce it, so for the code i have to create an array string or string array to parse it

Comment: the split case in string array is applied for better use of latitude and longitude separately,, you can even skip it